# N times data sorting with single loop

Tags: algorithm, sorting, vb6

i founded an logarithm of data sorting with single for...loop 
the code is following:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim a(10) As Integer
For i = 0 To 10
    a(i) = InputBox("enter a value")
Next
Dim counter As Integer
For i = 0 To 9
    If a(i) > a(i + 1) And i > -1 Then
        swap = a(i)
        a(i) = a(i + 1)
        a(i + 1) = swap
        i = i - 2
    End If
    If i = -2 Then
        i = i + 2
    End If
    counter = counter + 1
Next
For i = 0 To 10
    Print a(i)
Next
    MsgBox "this loop is runned " & counter
End Sub
```

this code is written in visual basic 6.0 
in short case this code is run N times but fact is that when data is in descending order and we want to convert it in ascending order. then this logarithm will run N*N times. means that if limit of array is 10 than this will run 100 times.

how can i short it that it should not run 100 times when limit of array is 10.

thanks for help:

Comment: A *logarithm* is a radically different thing from an *algorithm*.

Answer (score 0):

The code sample you have placed here appears to be an implementation of bubble sort. You are correct in saying that bubble sort is very inefficent for reverse ordered lists. (Worst case of O(N^2) time)

Sorting is a well studied problem in computer science. Doing a brief search will introduce you to a variety of discussions of the problems and possible solutions, and their known best (and worst) times.

For discusion of sorting particulary with respect to visual basic, you may find [this forum thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?473677-VB6-Sorting-algorithms-%28sort-array-sorting-arrays%29) of use. It's not really practical for me to repeat the content here without going on very long. Suffice to say that implementations of most well known sorting algorithms are available there.